# One Signal Phonegap não funciona

Tags: javascript, xml, apache-cordova, plugin, push-notification

Eu estou fazendo uma atualização de um app phonegap, ele compila na nuvem sem problemas, porém ao tentar fazer o login que estou usando o One Signal para fazê-lo, ele não acessa, não é problema com o api pois declarei que enviasse uma mensagem de erro. A versão que está rodando não apresenta o erro, apenas quando compilo no zip no site do phonegap, tentei fazer a build das versões anteriores, e se a build for feita a versão antiga também apresenta o erro. Alguém pode me dizer se há algo de errado com o xml. Ou alguém que tenha uma maior experiência com o One Signal para me dizer o que pode ser, segue o xml e o controler js:

```
                        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <widget id="com.vectra.odontomedica" version="1.0.6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
      <name>Vectra</name>
       <description>
           Desenvolvimento por Augusto Xavier
       </description>
       <author email="augustho.felipe@gmail.com" href="">
         Augusto Xavier
       </author>
       <content src="index.html"/>
        <access origin="*"/>

         <preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustPan" />
         <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
        <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
        <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
        <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
        <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="23"/>
        <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
        <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
        <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>
        <feature name="StatusBar">
          <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true"/>
             </feature>
                <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
               <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
               <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
               <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
               <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
              <allow-intent href="geo:*" />

                <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="4.0.0" />
                <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.0" />
                <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="2.2.1" />
                <plugin name="onesignal-cordova-plugin" spec="2.0.6" />



                       <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.3.0" />
                      <preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />
                      <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />

                           <platform name="android">
                           <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
                           <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>
                           <!-- you can use any density that exists in the Android project -->
                            <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-hdpi.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
                            <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-ldpi.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
                            <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-mdpi.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
                            <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-xhdpi.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>

                            <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-hdpi.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
                            <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-ldpi.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
                            <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-mdpi.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
                            <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-xhdpi.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
                              </platform>

                                 <platform name="ios">
                                    <!-- images are determined by width and height. The following are supported -->
                                   <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default~iphone.png" width="320" height="480"/>
                                   <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="960"/>
                                   <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" height="1024"/>
                                   <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" height="2048"/>
                                   <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" height="768"/>
                                   <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" height="1536"/>
                                   <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="1136"/>
                                   <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-667h.png" width="750" height="1334"/>
                                   <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-736h.png" width="1242" height="2208"/>
                                   <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" height="1242"/>
                                      </platform>


                                     <icon gap:platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29" />
                                     <icon gap:platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small-2x.png" width="58" height="58" />
                                     <icon gap:platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40" />
                                     <icon gap:platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-40-2x.png" width="80" height="80" />
                                     <icon gap:platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50" />
                                     <icon gap:platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-50-2x.png" width="100" height="100" />
                                     <icon gap:platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon.png" width="57" height="57" />
                                     <icon gap:platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-2x.png" width="114" height="114" />
                                     <icon gap:platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60" />
                                     <icon gap:platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60-2x.png" width="120" height="120" />
                                     <icon gap:platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60-3x.png" width="180" height="180" />
                                     <icon gap:platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72" />
                                     <icon gap:platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" height="144" />
                                     <icon gap:platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76" />
                                     <icon gap:platform="ios" src="res/icons/ios/icon-76-2x.png" width="152" height="152" />

                                           <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-36-ldpi.png"/>
                                           <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-48-mdpi.png"/>
                                           <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-72-hdpi.png"/>
                                           <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png"/>
                                           <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xxhdpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-144-xxhdpi.png"/>
                                          <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xxxhdpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-192-xxxhdpi.png"/>
                                          </widget>
```

O Controlador js:

```
                                                        (function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('LoginModule', ['CommonModule'])
    .controller('LoginController', LoginController);

LoginController.$inject = ['$scope', 'CommonService', '$ionicPopup', '$ionicLoading', '$state'];
function LoginController($scope, CommonService, $ionicPopup, $ionicLoading, $state) {
    //CommonService.sair();
    //CommonService.verificaLogado();
    $scope.popup = {};
    $scope.gravarSenha = false;
    $scope.esqueciData = {};
    var isGravarSenha = localStorage.getItem("gravarSenha");

    if (isGravarSenha != null && isGravarSenha != undefined && isGravarSenha != "") {
        isGravarSenha = JSON.parse(isGravarSenha);
        $scope.gravarSenha = true;
        $state.go("app.home");
    }

    var dadosOdonto = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("dadosOdonto"));

    if (dadosOdonto != undefined && dadosOdonto.Url != null) {
        $scope.logotipo = dadosOdonto.Url + "/logotipo.png";
    } else {
        $scope.logotipo = "img/logotipo.png";
    }

    $scope.cadastroNovo = function () {
        localStorage.setItem("configuracoes", "false");
        $state.go('cadastro');
    }

    $scope.clicarSenha = function (gravar) {
        $scope.gravarSenha = gravar;
    }

    $scope.logar = function (data) {
        $ionicLoading.show({
            template: 'Efetuando o login...'
        });
        window.plugins.OneSignal.getIds(function (ids) {
            data.deviceId = ids.userId;

            //data.deviceId = "";
            var chamaApi = CommonService.api("http://api.agafcomunicacao.com.br/api/login/entrar", data);
            chamaApi.get(data).$promise.then(function (retorno) {
                $ionicLoading.hide();
                if (retorno.Cro != undefined) {
                    if ($scope.gravarSenha == true) {
                        localStorage.setItem("gravarSenha", JSON.stringify(data));
                    } else {
                        localStorage.removeItem("gravarSenha");
                    }
                    localStorage.setItem("logado", JSON.stringify(retorno));
                    $state.go('app.home');
                } else {
                    $ionicPopup.alert({
                        title: 'Mensagem',
                        template: retorno.Mensagem
                    });
                }
            }, function (error) {
                $ionicLoading.hide();
                $ionicPopup.alert({
                    title: 'Ocorreu um erro!',
                    template: 'Erro ao realizar integração com a Api! Tente novamente mais tarde!'
                });
            });
        });
    }

    $scope.esqueciSenha = function () {
        var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
            template: '<input type="text" ng-model="popup.croEsqueciSenha" placeholder="Cro: ">',
            title: 'Recuperar senha pelo Cro',
            subTitle: 'Digite seu Cro',
            scope: $scope,
            buttons: [
                { text: 'Cancelar' },
                {
                    text: '<b>Solicitar</b>',
                    type: 'button-positive',
                    onTap: function (e) {
                        if (!$scope.popup.croEsqueciSenha) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                        } else {
                            return $scope.popup.croEsqueciSenha;
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        });

        myPopup.then(function (res) {
            if (res != undefined) {
                $ionicLoading.show({
                    template: 'Aguarde...'
                });
                var data = {};
                data.cro = res;
                var chamaApi = CommonService.api("http://api.agafcomunicacao.com.br/api/login/esquecisenha", data);
                chamaApi.get(data).$promise.then(function (retorno) {
                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                    $scope.popup = {};
                    $ionicPopup.alert({
                        title: 'Mensagem',
                        template: retorno.Mensagem
                    });
                }, function (error) {
                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                    $ionicPopup.alert({
                        title: 'Ocorreu um erro!',
                        template: 'Erro ao realizar integração com a Api! Tente novamente mais tarde!'
                    });
                });
            }
        });

    }

    $scope.recuperarSenha = function () {
        var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
            template: '<input type="text" ng-model="esqueciData.cro" placeholder="Cro:"></br><input type="text" ng-model="esqueciData.codigo" placeholder="Código:"> </br><input type="password" ng-model="esqueciData.novaSenha" placeholder="Nova Senha:">',
            title: 'Trocar Senha',
            subTitle: 'Digite o código enviado por e-mail e a nova senha',
            scope: $scope,
            buttons: [
                { text: 'Cancelar' },
                {
                    text: '<b>Recuperar</b>',
                    type: 'button-positive',
                    onTap: function (e) {
                        if (!$scope.esqueciData.cro || !$scope.esqueciData.codigo || !$scope.esqueciData.novaSenha) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                        } else {
                            var data = {};
                            data.codigo = $scope.esqueciData.codigo;
                            data.cro = $scope.esqueciData.cro;
                            data.novaSenha = $scope.esqueciData.novaSenha;
                            return data;
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        });


        myPopup.then(function (res) {
            if (res != undefined) {
                $ionicLoading.show({
                    template: 'Aguarde...'
                });
                var chamaApi = CommonService.api("http://api.agafcomunicacao.com.br/api/login/alterarsenha", res);
                chamaApi.get(res).$promise.then(function (retorno) {
                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                    $scope.esqueciData = {};
                    $ionicPopup.alert({
                        title: 'Mensagem',
                        template: retorno.Mensagem
                    });
                }, function (error) {
                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                    $ionicPopup.alert({
                        title: 'Ocorreu um erro!',
                        template: 'Erro ao realizar integração com a Api! Tente novamente mais tarde!'
                    });
                });
            }
        });

    }

}
             })();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri a solução o código estava descontinuado, ajustei sendo a documentação do OneSignal e instalei o plugin cordova-plugin-file que é responsável por gravar as informações do deviceid, assim consegui resolver o problema.